# GCM - Possible characters forming 'registration id'

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I was wondering if there are certain limitations regarding the registration id formatting in GCM.

In other words, are there any characters which it'll be safe to assume that will not be inside a valid GCM registration id?

I'm asking this since I would like to add a suffix (made of invalid characters) to such a valid Id, and use that suffix to identify a GCM registration id (instead of a C2DM one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "space" character if your use-case allows.

The GCM id might contains a-zA-Z0-9 and the "dash" character. (No citation, just observation)

And try not to use {} or [] as your separator in case the json string got confused.

Also note that there is no length limitation to the GCM id. It can come back shorter or longer some times depending on the id generation engine.

Comment: Got to the same conclusion myself (but with a newline character), thanks nontheless!

Comment: Can you please refer to the source of your answer?

Comment: No source, just observation as I have mentioned. :)

Comment: I also see underscores in registration ids.